# trying to define define build tag format with date branch

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

def build_tag_format = "--date='format-local:%y%m%d-%H%M%S' ${params['branch_name'] --pretty='%cd-%h'"

In above line branch definition is not acepting please help me on that. As of now i tried

def build_tag_format = "--date='format-local:%y%m%d-%H%M%S' --branch='$Branch' --pretty='%cd-%h'"

expecting to acept the build tag name date and branch name